How to use a Classic Google Managed certificate in a GKE ingress to generate https in load balancer
I have a Google Managed certificate which I am trying to use in my ingress, but it is not generating the HTTPS for the load balancer. Note that the managed certificate is showing under the Classic Certificates section, which is why I am using pre-shared-cert. I have also used self managed certs which are stored as a tls secret (and I see in the Web UI for the Ingress a line under Load Balancer Resources - TLS: my self managed cert. Those work as expected. Sure I can create the HTTPS in the load balancer, but that results in a different IP address, which ends up causing some url rewrite rules I need to not work...
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    networking.gke.io/pre-shared-cert: MY-GOOGLE-MANAGED-CLASSIC-CERT
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  name: MY-INGRESS
  namespace: MY-NAMESPACE
spec:
  rules:
  - host: MY-HOST-THAT-MATCHES-CERT
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: MY-SERVICE-NAME
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific

TLDR - How do I get a Classic Google Managed cert to result in a TLS being seen for the generated load balancer.

You can refer to this documentation for additional details.
Here are the things to consider :

The domain should pointing to the public IP address of your load balancer.

Double check the annotation, ensure that the pre-shared-cert annotation is correctly set to the exact name of your managed certificate.

Ensure that the certificate is in the Active state.

Ensure that your DNS configuration matches the hostname in your ingress and the certificate.


